# Tracking All Touchpad Events

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

My question is simple, is there a built-in method in Ubuntu/Linux (or some downloadable package), that makes it possible for me to track all the input events that come from my touchpad.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection  "evtest" but likely it will track everything.

Comment: Yeah that seems to do what I want. You should post it as an answer so I can at least give you credit for it haha.

Comment: here you go but I am already on 200 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki on [touchpad troubleshooting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) has some commands. The command [evtest](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest) is used to log events. From the 2nd link:

> evtest is not installed by default in ubuntu installation. Instead you must install it by using apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install evtest
```

> evtest should be used outside of X. This is because the X-driver grabs the device when active. This means that the kernel delivers hw events to the driver itself and not to any other device opener (ie-evtest). This is why we should switch to a VT so that the X-driver ungrabs the device node allowing others to receive events. (Thanks to Mattia Dongili and Peter Hutterer for help on this, in an email)
>
> evtest needs to be able to read from the device; in most cases this means it must be run as root.

From a terminal session ...

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

will show the event your touchpad uses. Look for something like
 H: Handlers=mouse2 event8`. And then on a virtual console type

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/eventX > ~/evtest
```

and the file `~/evtest` will contain all the events (do take care: it will get LARGE quickly). The link also says to use an identifier so you can find what you are looking for in the log quicker (like starting a session by pressing a A and pressing an A again when you want to stop this session).